# Reading a numpy saved file to a list

Tags: python, numpy

from an earlier numpy process I save a list which contains an array. Like this,

```
np.savetxt('CHARS.out', chars, delimiter=',', fmt="%s")
```

And when I try to read the file to a list for a later use using this code,

```
chars = open('chars.out', 'r')
chars = np.loadtxt(chars, delimiter=',')
```

I get the following error,

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'L'

Also using the following way to read it to list works but the output is not as expected

```
chars = open('chars.out', 'r')
chars = chars.readlines()
```

The output of the following is like this,

```
['L\n', '3\n', 'b\n', 'p\n',......
```

It has the new line character appended to the end of each character. How can I read the numpy savetxt file to a list or array in python?

Thank

Comment: What are the values in the file? It's not numbers since you have there `L`, `b`, etc. So why you want to use `numpy`?

Comment: It's a lengthy file with both numbers and letters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `savetxt` saves an array. If you pass a list that contains an array it effectively saves only the array.

Second, to read the array back you don't need to open a file but rather supply the file name to `genfromtxt`, like so:

```
chars = np.genfromtxt('chars.out', delimiter=',')
```

This puts the array in `chars`, and if you want an array inside a list, simply do `[chars]`.

**EDIT**

If you need to read the array as an array of strings, and also each string ends with a newline, which we can consider as a delimiter, then you read the array:

```
chars = np.genfromtxt('chars.out', delimiter='\n', dtype=str)
```

Comment: Hi, Like I said in the question the saved array/list contains both numbers and characters. With a small modification the code works chars = np.genfromtxt('CHARS.out', delimiter='\n', dtype="str") if you can change the answer to this I will accept it as the correct answer, I changed the delimiter to \n because the list of characters contained a , which gave an error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could strip the newline characters:

For Python 2.x:

```
strippedChars = map(lambda string: string.strip(), chars)
```

For Python 3.x

```
strippedChars = list(map(lambda string: string.strip(), chars))
```

Example with your code:

```
np.savetxt('CHARS.out', chars, delimiter=',', fmt="%s")
chars = open('chars.out', 'r')
chars = chars.readlines()
strippedChars = list(map(lambda string: string.strip(), chars))
```

Comment: I meant specifying no newline explicitly using newline='' but have since realized that won't give exactly what you want. The first method should work fine though.

Comment: How does the following code work? Can you put an example with the code I posted above thanks :)

Comment: It takes the output from the list `chars` and strips the newline characters off each element.

Comment: but when I print the chars variable it still has the new line character also when I print the stripped chars I get <map object at 0x01CAED30>

Comment: This also works I wish I could accept both answers as correct, but @Israel Unterman puts a one-liner that does the trick. I would have to accept that as the answer but I have up-voted yours :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the `\n` you can use list comprehension together with string slicing:

```
chars = [line[:-1] for line in open('chars.out', 'r')]
```